# Coldfusion Binary files

Tags: java, coldfusion, binary

I have some .cfm files which have a binary corrupted lines, and I used a Java decompiler to see the code of these files by converting its extension to .class.

What I ask about, how can I modify on these files, or even see the lines as a CFML template, and run it so I can access it on my server

```html
����
SourceFile :C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Clients\ent\www\ADMIN\clips\logclip.cfm
```

Comment: It does not sound like the files are corrupted, just [precompiled into byte code](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/Deploying+ColdFusion+Applications). If it is not your source code, you would have ask the owner/developer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my knowledge there is no way to get the original source back from the compiled cfm files because it is not actually encrypted or corrupted, it's really just a class file.

There is a bit more information about it here by Rupesh Kumar from the CF team

http://coldfused.blogspot.co.uk/2008/01/encrypted-cfml-templates.html

Comment: True. Though I am not sure why Rupesh uses the term "encrypted", since as he says, it is not really encrypted at all - just compiled into byte code ;-)

Comment: Good point - noticed I said the same in my answer :) Will update

Comment: Thanks for both of you John Whish and Leigh

Answer (score 0):

2 answers here:

If you are speaking of the compiled class files and you have the cfm files you can safely delete the classfiles (in the "cfclasses" directory of your instance). ColdFusion will recompile them when next your run the source file. The big gotcha is, if this is a high traffic site  and you delete ALL the files, then you may drag your server down as CF has to recompile everything. In that case you might want to be more selective.

If you mean you are seeing nonsense encryption in a CF file and the only readible part of the file is at the top (a sort of header that tells you what it is), then you are working with *encrypted CFM files* - CF provides (or provided) a utility to encrypt and deploy CFM files to hide source code. The CF engine can *unecrypt* these files into regular CF then compile them down into class files. The encryption used was (in the past) quite trivial and not much protection at all. I have unecrypted these files in the past for site owners who owned their code but whose developer had chosen to encrypt them and not provide source copies.

YOu can find methods to unecrypt them (and even utilities to do it) in the wild if this is your issue. My only caution would be *be sure you have a right* to the code - there was a time when many devs sold encrypted custom tags and widgets - encrypted to prevent them from propogating without license.

Comment: cfclasses were at ColdFusion MX 6 and old versions and we don't generate these files, but they're already existed.

Comment: Dev - yes, they exist when you run a .cfm file. If CF does not find a compiled class it compils it and puts it in the cfclasses directory. If you delete these files CF recreates them from the original cfm files.